# How to wake up when the app has been updated?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, app-store, apple-push-notifications

I did contact the Apple Developper Technical Support and they answer me that "*No, there are no APIs that will tell you that an app has been updated.*"

However, I really need to wake up  my app when the user update it to last version. 
Because my push notification system has changed in the last version and the user must be registered to the new platform in order to continue to receive notifications.
To register the user, the app should launch.

Does anyone know how I could do that ?

Some of my apps are in Objective C, others are in Swift.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I believe "wakeup" here means starting the application that has been updated asap. As far as I know, that's not possible. What you can do is to prompt the user to launch the app.

Comment: @Krishna Chaitanya Amjuri It could be a solution... Can you tell me how I can do that please ?

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to launch your app automatically after an update. This would be a horrible user experience.

This is what you could do instead:

### 1. Release notes

Write at the top of the release notes in the AppStore, that the users should start the app to continue receiving notifications.

### 2. One last notification for the old versions

If it's possible four you, you could send a notification from the old system that tells the users to update and launch the app.

Comment: Is it not possible to launch the app in background ? To avoid bad user experience. 
Thank you for your advice. If I don't find a solution, that is what I will do.

Comment: @Vanessa as far as I know, the only way to execute code without actually presenting the app, is via silent push-notifications. And that seems not to be an option for you

Comment: No, it isn't... :-(

Answer (score 0):

You can  use background fetch in order to quick execute  a small part of code and show an notification into user screen. But in this case you need your own server where you store current app version you have released.
this is a wonder tutorial how you can use background fetch.
 https://www.raywenderlich.com/143128/background-modes-tutorial-getting-started

but remember you can not push your application into foreground in iOS.

Comment: does background fetch work if my app is juste installed (new version downloaded) but never launched ?

Comment: No. The user have to launxh your app each time after reboot

Comment: Or use push notifixations